# Need help to use node-soap module

Tags: web-services, node.js, soap

I have to make a server to update some device.
They asked me to use node.js and the device send a soap request.
I need to check the parameters to verify the version. So I decided to use the node-soap module. (The WSDL file I use is a local file)
But I can't find how to recover the value of those parameters.
I read the node-soap spec, but I couldn't find how to do that. :/
Here is my code (I didn't do much yet because I'm stuck because of this) :

```
var myService = {
    ActiaProxyAPI: { //MyService
        ActiaProxyAPI: { //MyPort
              GetData: function(args) { //MyFunction
                    if (args.i-uiType == "11") {
                        var ID = args.i-pcIdentifiant;
                        var reg=new RegExp("[ $]+", "g"); //parse the string (actually works)
                        var tableau=ID.split(reg); 
                        console.log(tableau[4] );
                      }
                  return {
                      name: args.o-poData 
                  };
              }

          }
      }
  };

  var xml = require('fs').readFileSync('./wsdl/ActiaProxyAPI.wsdl', 'utf8'),
      server = http.createServer(function(request,response) {
          response.end("404: Not Found: "+request.url);
      });

  server.listen(8080);
  soap.listen(server, '/wsdl', myService, xml);
```

Comment: What is the question exactly? I see you are asking something about WSDL, but I'm not sure what the problem exactly is.

Comment: I need to do a web service to update a device, but my question is how to recover the value of the parameters sent by the device (i-pcIdentifiant ...) by a soap request.

P.S.: sorry for my english, I'm french.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found how to retrieve the arguments' value : instead of *args.i-uiType* I used *args["i-uiType"]* , and instead of *name: args.o-poData* :
*'tns:GetDataResponse': {'o-poData': result}*

Well I hope this can help other people, because it works for me !